# Wordpress extra spaces breaks layout

Tags: php, wordpress, layout, whitespace

I am creating and developing a custom Wordpress theme and I am struggling with one issue, which is making me crazy and I can't find any fix and can't figure out, what I am doing wrong...

There is some extra spaces added in output which breaks the layout and creates empty space

here is my source code (index.php):

```
<div class="c6">
    <h4>news</h4>
    <?php query_posts('showposts=3'); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else : ?>

        <p><?php _e('No posts were found!', 'unqvsn-framework'); ?></p>

    <?php endif ?>

    <p class="articles-nav-prev"><?php next_posts_link(__('&raquo; Older Posts', 'unqvsn-framework')); ?></p>

</div>
```

and here is also code for the left column sidebar, where it is happening too (as well as for each sidebar I create):

```
<h4>Line up</h4>
<div class="sidebar"><?php get_sidebar('lineup-sidebar'); ?></div>
```

and here is the output with inspected code in the browser (Chrome, the same happens in Firefox):

[Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/a/img13/1392/screenissued.png)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unwanted white-space can be caused if your files are saved as UTF8.

To fix it, try re-saving the affected files as UTF-8 without BOM, to do this in Notepad++, just go to Encoding-> Encode in UTF-8 without BOM and save.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

[What's different between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is adding html comments in between your php tags to prevent the extra whitespace

```
<h4>news</h4><!-- no whitespace
    --><?php query_posts('showposts=3'); ?><!-- no whitespace
    etc...
    --><p class="articles-nav-prev">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this doesn't helped. that freaking whitespaces were added right after the html comment....

Comment: yayks, I just find the solution - I have to re-save all my files with encoding converted to UTF-8 without BOM (Byte order mark) after that, all whitespaces are gone!

Comment: I was about to add that as a comment, it's happened to me before except instead of whitespace I got three characters appearing.

Comment: @martincarlin87 please post it as answer, and I will mark it as valid answer, as I am not able to comment my own question for next 7 hours with reputation so low... :) thank you!

Comment: @unqvsn I've posted an answer now with some links for reference.